# How to remove Highcharts.com?

Tags: java, android, using

I have gone through many solution to remove the Highcharts.com watermark from Piechart,Barchart while implementing HighChart SDK.But,sorry say that no one worte the proper solution.How to write code inside the Java Class.See below solution,it might help you out.....Correct me if i'm wrong..
Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

credits: {
enabled: false
},

Use this in script file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
HICredits credits = new HICredits();
credits.setEnabled(false);
options.setCredits(credits);
```

Comment: HICredits credits = new HICredits();

    credits.setEnabled(false);

    options.setCredits(credits);

Comment: use this solution

Comment: not working bro. still showing that water mark

Answer (score -1):

let credits = HICredits() credits.enabled = false options.credits = credits

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!